# How can I get an indicator icon for new updates?

Tags: 11.04, unity, update-manager

I don’t want Update Manager popping up on its own, but I do want to be notified that there are new updates.  In older Ubuntu releases (I don’t remember *how* old), an icon would display in the notification area if there were updates available, with a different look if there were security updates.  I could either bring up a terminal and do `sudo apt-get upgrade` or just click the icon to bring up Update Manager.  In 10.10 I ran this command to get that behavior back:

`gconftool -s --type bool /apps/update-notifier/auto_launch false`

That was working great, but now that I’m running 11.04 with Unity, nothing shows up at all.  If I do `sudo apt-get upgrade` in terminal it installs updates if there are any, but there aren’t always updates and I’d like the nice non-invasive reminder icon back if at all possible.  I’ve read about Unity hiding some indicator icons so maybe that’s what’s happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I logged in this morning and had my updates icon, just as I wanted!  Here’s what worked to get this working using commands in the terminal:

1. Check what’s already allowed using `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist` since you probably don’t want to turn anything off.  My default value was `['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'scp-dbus-service']`.
2. If you suspect you have other missing icons (for example, Pidgin), you can find the correct values to add to the list with `grep TrayChild ~/.xsession-errors` ― if something tried to add itself to the tray it will show up with the name the system knows it by.
3. Add `update-notifier` (and anything else you found in step 2) to the list.  If you had the same default values as I did, use this command:  `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'scp-dbus-service', 'update-notifier']"`
4. Now set update notifier not to auto-launch (this is from the question):  `gconftool -s --type bool /apps/update-notifier/auto_launch false`

Next time there are updates, you get the icon notifying you ― hooray!

Answer (score 1):

> I’ve read about Unity hiding some indicator icons so maybe that’s what’s happening here?

If you do not have dconf-tools installed, install it. Run it (from the terminal or from the launcher: if you do not see it when you type dconf in the launcher, check Main Menu settings), go to desktop>unity>panel. Here you have the list of all classes that Unity allows in the systray.

Add your class there, or change the whole string to ['all'] to allow everything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray','update-manager']"
```

Comment: i tried `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist` and noticed i also had `scp-dbus-service` in there, so ran this:  `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'scp-dbus-service', 'update-manager']"`.  nothing yet but i did just update before posting the question...  is there a way to just add a value to that list rather than needing to enter the entire thing?

Comment: according to `grep TrayChild ~/.xsession-errors`, it’s actually `update-notifier`, so i changed to that.  still waiting for something to show up though.

Comment: Ok, wait for updates :)