# Why Update Manager doesn't use indicators?

Tags: indicator, update-manager

Informing about system updates seems like a perfect match for an indicator (it could appear or change color when there are new updates). Instead of that we have an annoying popup window, which demands immediate attention. I cannot imagine that nobody thought about that before, and it doesn't seem difficult to implement, so I assume there has to be a reason behind that?

Comment: I just want to say I agree... and no I do not know the thought process behind this...

Comment: Possible duplicate?  You can turn off the default pop-up and have the app indicator show as per this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/42140/how-can-i-get-an-indicator-icon-for-new-updates

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still curious why this is not the default, and why it hasn't been ported to indicators (this is a tray icon).

Answer (score 2):

There is an indicator in 11.04. It shows gray for suggested updates and red for critical updates. It works in classic Gnome, and in Unity as well. I can't remember if it was in 10.10 or not.

[image: Update Manager]

The notification for updates is the sun-like icon in the middle. This is actually displayed because I have a package manager open, but the optional update icon is the same. It shows in red when there are critical updates. I don't see any settings under updates that control whether or not this is displayed, is I'm not sure why sure why you don't see it. I'm set for auto-download, manual install, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: I use 11.04 and I still get the popup. Could you include a screenshot, please?

Comment: Thanks, and upvoted. However, it looks like you had to configure it manually (see foofredom's link).

Comment: I don't recall doing that ... it may be set that way as I've been upgrading rather than installing fresh for the last half dozen releases or so.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently developing an application which does just what you asked for, mainly because the update management of ubuntu is not satisfactory for me:

[image: Link to screenshot]

You can download the sources at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/indicator-updatemanager) (External downloads). It's in an early development stage and might still have bugs. But it works for me :-)